# Discord Bot which fetches message from a channel to another not sending messages and giving error

Tags: python, discord.py

Please anyone help to solve it. Bot is being run successfully without getting error but bot is not working / not sending messages.
It is not working.

This is the code:

```
try:
    import requests,json,asyncio,pytz,time,discord
    from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
    import datetime
    import asyncio
    from pytz import timezone
    from discord.ext.commands import Bot
    from discord.ext import commands
    import sys
    import subprocess
except Exception as e:
    print("Import Error:",str(e))

# input all datas
bot1_token = "bot1_token"
bot2_token = "bot2_token"

bot_prefix = "#"

Vedantu_channels = ["873257403217481738"] 

client = discord.Client()


bot = Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event 
async def on_ready(): 
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")    

ch = bot.get_channel(853480780214698014)
   
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user.name}")


@client.event
async def on_message(message): 

    if message.channel.id in Vedantu_channels:
        content = message.content
        if "w1" in content:
            if "w1" in content or "w1" in content:
                await ch.send("1")


    if message.channel.id in Vedantu_channels:
        content = message.content
        if "w2" in content:
            if "w2" in content or "w2" in content:
                await ch.send("2")

      
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.create_task(bot.start(bot2_token))
loop.create_task(client.start(bot1,bot=True))

while True:
    try:
        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        finally:
            loop.stop()
    except Exception as e:
       print("Event loop error:", e)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?
I am not getting any error but messages not send bot to channel.

There is no error messages that I have gotten.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. Maybe it never run code (or bot) which should send it.

Comment: why do you check exactly the same three times: `if "w1" in content: if "w1" in content or "w1" in content:` ? It makes no sense.

Comment: `message.channel.id` is integer number but `Vedantu_channels` has strings.

Answer (score -1):

Well, your code is very complicated. You can simplify it a lot.

Your errors:

- You must put all imports in multiple imports, and remove the try and except
- You can't do variables with underscores and numbers
- You can't use `discord.Client()` and `commands.Bot()`
- It isn't recommended to use two bots in a same project
- You can't use client and bot as the same time
- You must use [] when you have more than one object

**simplified code**

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from pytz import timezone
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed

import discord
import json
import asyncio

import pytz
import requests
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
import time

TOKEN = "paste the bot's token here"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#")
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(bot))

#just an example command
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(853480780214698014)
    await channel.send("Hello!")
    await ctx.send("You can see my greetings in another channel")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Whay do you mean by "You can't do variables with underscores and numbers"

Comment: You can't do variables with _ and numbers

Comment: How do I "do variables" and what do underscores and numbers have to do with them?

Comment: Also, why do you have to change the imports?

Comment: Why can't I use `discord.Client()` and `commands.Bot()`?

Comment: You can't use them as the same time. It's just that it is odd and it will confuse you later